# Multiple layouts with different settings per category QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have a shapefile with polygons and with two different columns. One column contains the type the other column contains a date. I can change the symbology of the shapefile per category so that all the types that are the same will get the same color. I can do the same for the dates.
But those types sometimes change, as do the dates. And so i change the columns frequently.

I would like to make 2 kinds of layout that I can review when something small has changed. So I don't have to change all the settings again. The first one I would like it to show the shapefile including categories by type; the second one by date. But I would like it to be able to change when I change the settings. Is this possible, and yes how?

Comment: Duplicate your layer, and in one symbolize categories by type and the other categories by date.  Make a layout the way you want and turn off the date layer.  Lock the layout layers and styles.  Duplicate the layout and this time turn off the type categories and turn on the date.  When done lock it.  When you want to change things unlock the particular layout and turn on the layer you want to change and make your changes.  Then lock.  If you had a lot of layers to show differently in each layout then you could group each for different layouts to turn on or off easily.

Comment: You may want to use layer style, maybe in conjonction with map theme (see : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#managing-custom-styles and https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=map%20themes#configuring-map-themes)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. To make a couple of styles is indeed a solution to my problem